# Replace specific row in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

Initially, this is what we can see when I run `SELECT * FROM block_custom;`:

```
+-----+------------------+--------+-----------+
| bid | body             | info   | format    |
+-----+------------------+--------+-----------+
|   1 | Block1 body here | Block1 | full_html |
|   2 | Block2 body here | Block2 | full_html |
|   3 | Block3 body here | Block3 | full_html |
+-----+------------------+--------+-----------+
```

In order to replace `info` and `body`of table `block_custom`, I'm using below query:

```
update block_custom set info = replace(info,'Block2','Block2new');
update block_custom set body = replace(body,'body here','newbody here');
```

This is explanation of my query:

```
update [table_name] set [field_name] = replace([field_name],'[string_to_find]','[string_to_replace]');
```

When running this query to change `body`, it will replace in all row of column `body`.

How to make it change only in row 2 (`bid 2`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, restrict it with a `WHERE` clause.

```
... WHERE bid=2
```

Comment: But how to use the `WHERE bid=3` in one line? (All example I found using clause is not one line)